# GdxRuntimeException: File not found

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm following [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) tutorial on libgdx and I've hit a bit of a snag. I just finished the 'loading the assets' section. When I tried to run it, instead of getting the rain sound and a pink background, like the tutorial claims, I get errors up the wazoo. Here's my Drop.java:

```
package com.badlogic.drop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Drop implements ApplicationListener {

    Texture dropImage;
    Texture bucketImage;
    Sound dropSound;
    Music rainMusic;


    @Override
    public void create() {      
        // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
          dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
          bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

          // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
          dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
          rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));

          // start the playback of the background music immediately
          rainMusic.setLooping(true);
          rainMusic.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

and here are my errors. (Ones I think are important are bolded)

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: droplet.PNG
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
**Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: droplet.PNG**
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:122)
    at com.badlogic.drop.Drop.create(Drop.java:21)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
**Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: droplet.PNG (Internal)**
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:580)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 8 more

The weird thing is, I *have* all of the pngs and music files in my assets/data folders. They're all there, but the code isn't seeing them. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: If the files are in `assets/data`, try using `dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/droplet.png"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are using

`Gdx.files.internal`  <- This only gets you to the assets folder. You have to direct it into any sub-directories you are wanting files from also.

and your files are in assets/data use

`Gdx.files.internal("data/droplet.png")`

Be sure to change all your other references also to the correct location.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed since the original asset was under data, that that was where assets went.

Comment: Yea I did that same tutorial when I started with libgdx.  Find me in my chat if you have any other questions: [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33594/room-for-conversations-with-obiemd5)